# Match existing user profile with facebook, gmail and twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have built a custom login system.  It's working fine, but because users often forget their user login details, I want to use oauth for Gmail and Facebook access.

How can I match the existing user data with the Facebook or Gmail data?

Comment: What do you mean "match the existing user data with the Facebook or Gmail data"? They only way to do that is have a current (logged in) user connect their login to their Facebook/Gmail account. The user has to do that. You cannot do it for them. [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) can make this task easier for you.

Comment: by example. Some has a username: John@example.com. And now i want that john can have access with his facebook account to his john@example.com information. How know can i match the facebook login with the right username?

Comment: If that user is logged in then you know the username, right? If that user is not logged in then **there is no way** to match his Facebook login with his account. (Unless you're the NSA)

Comment: I cannot give you the code to do that. [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=omniauth) has a few good screencasts on this topic. Have a look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an user and it uses facebook or gmail OAuth for login, you can identify it by looking in your current users table by his e-mail (assuming you required e-mail confirmation in your system, or else it can become a real mess). Twitter, by other hand, doesn't allow you to see the e-mail from the user, so you will have to look for an alternate way. The more straight-forward way to unite the user account with an external user account is simply ask to add bound the accounts in the first OAuth login.

Forgetting their login details doesn't seems to be the best motive to use OAuth, but to implement a "forgot password/login" feature. OAuth is supposed to improve your users experience by being connected to other services as well, and use the same "friends" or "share" things in an easier way. (This seems to be my personal opinion since I have no source and @Mischa does not agree with that). However, as you noticed, it also simplify your user management if you don't want to implement one yourself.

Comment: Not having to remember hundreds of different usernames/passwords for every different site is the best thing about OAuth. As for the remark about email: that's a very unreliable method. He could be using a different email address than on Facebook. The only reliable way is to have the user be logged in to your site when he makes the connection. Then, when you make the connection, you know who it is, because he's the `current_user`.

Comment: @Mischa it is true that is not reliable, but sometimes you need to just throw out reliability in order to make things simpler. If he is using other e-mail on facebook, it will have a new account on the site, no big deal about that. If the user wants to join his facebook account with the original site account, you can always have an option to let him do this manually. I would say that most people uses one e-mail for registration in every site - I don't have data, but I'm sure you will feel that this is right. So why not simplify it?